# Chartjs: Make some ticks (Sunday, Saturday) red

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, label

I try to make the ticks the red. but it not working. When labels has not the labels - Sa/Su it work. All labels - grey, but when i have Su or Sa labels make just black color

```
   ticks: {
          fontSize: 9,
          fontColor: curLabels.map((item) => {
            if(item === 'Su' || item === 'Sa')
              return 'red';
            return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)';
          }),
          maxRotation: 0,
        },
```

Edited:

```
  <div style={{height: '100%'}} className='position-relative'>
        <Line
          key='lineChart17'
          data={dataForChart}
          options={lineOptions}
          style={{height: '90px', padding: '5px', width: '100%'}}
          redraw
        />
      </div>
```

Options for chart. I get error - ticks has not properties major. In console it just the string - Mo/Th/Fr/We/Su ...:

```
 const lineOptions = {
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    layout:{
      padding:{
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 5,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          tickMarkLength: 1,
        },

        ticks: {
          fontSize: 9,
          fontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          maxRotation: 0,
          major: {
            enabled: true,
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fontColor: 'red'
          },
        },
        afterBuildTicks: (scale, ticks) => {
          ticks.forEach(t => {
            t.major = (t === 'Su');
          });
          return ticks;
        },

      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          tickMarkLength: 1,
        },
      }],
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Chart.js documentation, the option [`ticks.fontColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) doesn't accept an `array` but a simple `string`.

You can however define the style of your weekend `ticks` through the [`ticks.major`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#major-tick-configuration) configuration as follows.

```
ticks: {
  major: {
     enabled: true,
     fontStyle: 'bold',
     fontColor: 'red'
  }
},
```

Further you need to mark the desired ticks as `major` through the [`afterBuildTicks`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks) callback.

```
afterBuildTicks: (scale, ticks) => {
  ticks.forEach(t => {
    const day = new Date(t.value).getDay();
    t.major = (day == 0 || day == 6);
  });
  return ticks;
}
```

Please take a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const dates = [];
let day = new Date('2020-01-01');
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dates.push(new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), day.getDate()));
    day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
};

function generateData() {
  return dates.map(d => ({ x: d, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 }));
};

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: generateData(),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }        
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'dd D MMM',
            month: 'dd D MMM'            
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'dd D MMM'
        },
        ticks: {  
          major: {      
            enabled: true,
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fontColor: 'red'
          }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: (scale, ticks) => {
          ticks.forEach(t => {
            const day = new Date(t.value).getDay();
            t.major = (day == 0 || day == 6);
          });
          return ticks;
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {      
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 2
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you. I try this, but it not work for me. AfterBuildTick is not called

Comment: i fixed. but now i get the error: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'major' on string 'Su'`

Comment: Please show more of your code together with the data you're trying to render in the chart.