# Is there a way to set different colors on each line of labels in char js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chart js I'm finding a way to make different colors of each line

Here is the example of my code and an example image

[image: example]

```
let Labels1 = [
  ['A','40'],
  ['B', '       '+50],
  ['C','     '+ 60],
  ['D','70'],
  ['E',80 + '    '],
  ['F',100 + '   ']
]
export const radardata = {
    labels: Labels1,
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: '#fcd5ce',
            borderColor: 'rgb(194, 116, 161)',
            data: radarData,
            
        },
    ],
    
};


export let radarchartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: false,
        scales: {
            
            r : {
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                pointLabels: {
                    // color: [['red','black'],'blue','black','yellow','orange','green'],
                },
                    // padding: 5,
                    // font:{
                    //     size: 18,
                    //     weight: "bold"
                    // },
                              
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                },
                
                
                },
            

            },
        plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                datalabels: {            
                   display: false    
                },

                
            },
        }
```

I want to make for example 'A' and '40' different color and font size.

I tried to put html code in label but found it's hard to apply in chart js.

And tried setting different colors like

color: [['green','black'],.....] on the option part but failed.

Is there a way to do it in chart js?

Comment: i don't think this is possible

Comment: This answer may help you find a solution for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665630/2358409

Comment: Actually @uminder your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62862487/13762301 seems closer to the mark.